# Removing Icloud Account from old phone

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have just swapped from an Iphone 6s to an Iphone SE. I reset my old phone and and erased all contents and settings but I forgot to remove my icloud account. I've logged on to my icloud account and looked under 'my phone' but all i can see on there is my new phone. When I go into account settings I can see my old iphone 6s and there is an option to remove it from account. If I do this will that mean that my icloud had been removed? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Removing your iCloud account from the iPhone 6S from icloud.com or any other Apple device on Find My will mean that your iCloud account has been removed. Was Find My iPhone enabled on the iPhone 6S? If it was, then that means that the iCloud account was automatically removed when erasing the device (your device should have prompted for your Apple ID and Password). If you still have access to the iPhone 6S and want to make sure that it is removed completely, you should probably set up the phone again and use your Apple ID. Then, remove it from Settings > Your Name > Sign Out (at the bottom) and erase the device (Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings).

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me as I’m really not very techy. I have no idea if find my iphone was enabled on my old iphone 6s. I did the whole erase all content and settings and when i went to a site to sell my phone they asked me to check that i had removed my account. When i login to icloud.com my 6s doesn’t show under find phone i can only see it in account settings. So are you saying that that means it has been removed and all i need to do now is remove it from account settings? If i set up my old phone again would i have to download everything again from my iCloud? Sorry for questions

Comment: No problem just set it up as a brand new phone and sign into your Apple ID. Then, you can properly remove it using the sign out button. After that, an erase should do it. It might still show in settings but you still can have the confidence that you have properly removed it.